# Ignore duplication constraints when bulk inserting into Postgresql or MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

When issuing a bulk [insert statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp), how can we ignore (supress) the exception thrown by DB and/or JDBC driver ?

Lets say I want to bulk insert some Users and I have an Id as a unique key

```
INSERT INTO users
(id,name,age,email,pass_code) 
VALUES 
(1,'Mark',18,'mail@mail.com',123),
(2,'Zak',18,'mail@mail.com',123),
(3,'Djigi',18,'mail@mail.com',123),

(1,'James Petkov',18,'mail@mail.com',123), --Duplicated by id ? 

(4,'Kinkinikin',18,'mail@mail.com',123),
(5,'A bula bula ',18,'mail@mail.com',123),
(6,'Shakazulo',18,'mail@mail.com',123);
```

How to tell the engine MySQL/PostgreSQL to continue inserting the remaining records ?

Is this supported in SQL at all ?

Comment: Then don't make this ID the primary key of your table.  Since it is in duplicate anyway, let MySQL assign an ID.

Comment: is your question more about continuing insertions when errors are encountered along the way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The ideas is not about generating ids but rather to suppress the exception when inserting duplicate records.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  The error is there for a reason.  If not primary key then don't read it in as such.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What I am asking, generally, if you are doing bulk insert and you have duplicate record regardless of which key is duplicated how can you continue the operation and skip the duplicated key, that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, you can ignore the failing rows with

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

A more general solution is to run each `INSERT` separately and ignore errors.